# What does it mean to arrange f(n) before g(n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

Just attended my first Data Structure Algorithm class and I do not understand it at all. One question given to me was:

Arrange the following functions into increasing order; that is, () should come before () in your list if and only if () is (()).

```
3^2n , 5n lg n + 20n , n^0 , 2^lg n , 16 ^lg n
```

So what should I do? Substitute n as 1 and work each function out before sorting them?

Comment: Do you know what (()) means? That's really the important part here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955186/arrange-the-following-growth-rates-in-increasing-order-o-n-log-n2-o-35

Comment: Hint: what is O(g(n)) if g(n) = 3^(2n)? That is, what is O(3^(2n))? What about O(5n lg n + 20n)? What about O(n^0)?

Comment: @jwodder To my understanding, it means that f(n) ≤ g(n)

Comment: @EugeneS Thanks for the link! Giving it a good read through.

Comment: @SethDifley hmm I still do not understand the Big-O notation to answer you..

Comment: I'm wondering about the question, why is it comparing f(n) to O(g(n))? Seems the ordering is to based on the list of expressions for n sufficiently large enough that the ordering of the functions no longer changes for greater values of n.

Comment: Right I think i figured it out. Can someone help me take a look?

n^0 , 2^lg n, 16^lg n , 5n lg n + 20n , 3^2n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd suggest you to go and read about [the big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Then, if you'll take a look at the link @EugeneS gave you in the comment you'll notice this:

```
O(n^n) > O(n!) > O(α^n) > O(n^α) > O(log(n)) > O(1)
```

So lets break things down a bit:

```
1. O(3^2n) = O(α^n)
2. O(5nlogn+20n) = O(nlogn)
3. O(n^0) = O(1)
4. O(2^logn) = O(α^logn)
5. O(16^logn) = O(α^logn)
```

Now you said

> () should come before () in your list if and only if () is (()).

Can you arrange them now? According to what you understood on big-O and the list above.
The right arrangement would be

```
O(α^n) > O(α^logn) > O(α^logn) > O(nlogn) > O(1)

1 > 5 > 4 > 2 > 3
```

**Note to yourself:** This is really the basics and it is very important, so make sure you understand this before moving on with your course material.

Comment: Note that `a^log(n)=e^(log(a)*log(n))=n^log(a)`, which should simplify some cases.